# MySQL UPDATE múltiplos campos sob a mesma condição (IF ou CASE)

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Amigos, necessito de ajuda.

Tenho estes 2 queries:

```
UPDATE leilaov
  SET seconds = CASE
     WHEN (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
       OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
       OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
       OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())) THEN seconds-1
  END
WHERE numero12345 = 1


UPDATE leilaov
  SET seconds = IF((mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
               OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
               OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
               OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())), seconds-1, seconds)
WHERE numero12345 = 1
```

Ambos funcionam perfeitamente e não há diferenças significativas no tempo de execução. O problema é que necessito de actualizar múltiplos campos e não apenas um.

Qual é a sintaxe para actualizar múltiplos campos? Terei de repetir a condição para cada campo?

Deverei utilizar CASE ou IF? Ou será que existe uma opção melhor?

Antecipadamente obrigado.

Comment: Por multiplos campos você quer dizer vários registros com o `numero12345` diferente?

Comment: Não @Luis Henrique. No exemplo em cima estou a actualizar o campo seconds. Necessito de actualizar outros campos (ex: mesini e diaini) do mesmo registro. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe para múltiplos campos é:

```
UPDATE [tabela]
    SET campo1 = valor1,
        campo2 = valor2 
        ...
WHERE ...
```

Quanto à sua query, parece que ela poderia ser reformulada assim:

```
UPDATE leilaov
  SET seconds = seconds-1
  -- outros campos aqui conforme necessário
WHERE numero12345 = 1
  AND (
     (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) 
     AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) 
     AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) 
     AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
     OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
     OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
     OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW()))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar criar uma função:

```
    DELIMITER ;;

    CREATE FUNCTION obterSeconds (horaini INT, diaini INT, mesini INT, seconds INT) 
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        RETURN 
            CASE
                WHEN (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini = HOUR(NOW()) AND minutoini <= MINUTE(NOW())) 
                   OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini < DAYOFMONTH(NOW())) 
                   OR (mesini = MONTH(NOW()) AND diaini = DAYOFMONTH(NOW()) AND horaini < HOUR(NOW()))
                   OR (mesini < MONTH(NOW())) 
                   THEN seconds-1
    END;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

e chamar assim:

```
UPDATE leilaov
  SET seconds = obterSeconds(horaini, diaini, mesini, seconds) 
WHERE numero12345 = 1
```

Mas eu deixo o meu alerta, o seu CASE não tem uma instrução ELSE e, em caso nenhuma das condições sejam verdadeiras irá postar NULL, não sei se é esse o pretendido, se seconds for NOT NULL a aplicação vai obter um erro de SQL dizendo que seconds não pode receber um valor nulo (e voce pode ignorar) OU se seconds for NULLABLE talvez voce queria adicionar algumas condições na clausula WHERE do seu update. Ou, talvez adicione um ELSE na instrução CASE.